# Screen turns black when using launcher icons

Tags: unity, 14.04, compiz, launcher, icons

I may have found a new bug, I can't find anything resembling the problem I'm having.
I recently upgraded to 14.04 from 13.10, and the launcher is virtually useless. If I hover over any launcher icon or right click any launcher icon, my entire screen goes black, save for my mouse cursor. No launcher, no panel, nothing. Upon moving my mouse away from the icon, or clicking outside the launcher space, the screen returns to normal. I'm guessing this has something to do with either Unity or Compiz, or my context menu is bugged.
I've already tried restarting Unity, Compiz, my computer, and using the Unity reset tool. I'll keep looking around, but if anyone has any suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: Can you please post the solution as an answer so others can benefit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP wrote:

> I figured it out! I had to reset Unity, following the guide here -> http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-reset-compiz-and-unity-in-ubuntu.html Note that it will take a bit, so don't be impatient. Wait until your launcher is reset, then you can close out of the terminal. Note that you will need to edit and restore any settings you had before, including those in compiz.